# Кросскомпиляция ActiveMQ-cpp

Tags: c++, qtcreator, кросс-компиляция, activemq

Нужна подробная инструкция по кросс-компиляции `ActiveMQ-cpp` на `ubuntu 15 64bit` для `ARM 32 bit`. Компилятор **arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++**. Что кросскомпилировать прежде (необходимо и достаточно), с какими флагами? Гоогл дает только отрывочные инструкции.

**Пока имею вот это:**

Конфигурация для сборки `activemq-cpp` из исходников:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr --with-sysroot=/home/rishat/olimex CXX=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

в результате получаю:

```
... (много строк)
checking size of wchar_t... configure: error: in `/home/rishat/Source/activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4_arm':
configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (wchar_t)
See `config.log' for more details
```

Содержимое config.log по этому вопросу:

```
configure:17217: result: no
configure:17235: checking for wchar_t
configure:17235: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -g -O2  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:17235: $? = 0
configure:17235: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -g -O2  conftest.cpp >&5
conftest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
conftest.cpp:61:14: error: expected primary-expression before 'wchar_t'
 if (sizeof ((wchar_t)))
              ^
conftest.cpp:61:14: error: expected ')' before 'wchar_t'
conftest.cpp:62:14: error: expected ')' before ';' token
      return 0;
              ^
conftest.cpp:62:14: error: expected ')' before ';' token
configure:17235: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

Все необходимые пакеты устанавливал "нормальным" способом:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libtool-bin
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev 
sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev
```

Подозреваю, что и их надо тоже кросс-компилить, но хотелось бы иметь необходимый минимум пакетов и флагов, чтобы не увязнуть в этом окончательно

Исходники `activemq-cpp`: http://activemq.apache.org/cms/download.html

Исходники `apr`: https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi

---

Comment: курите yocto и bitbake умаетесь все зависимости руками собирать

Comment: @JK_Action боюсь, что на изучение `bitbake` уйдет еще больше времени. Даже не представляю, как он может значительно облегчить этот занудный процесс

Comment: Вы даже не представляете на сколько он упростит вашу жизнь. Я через это прошел, собирать linux ПО вручную весело до поры до времени. bitbake это инструмент кросс сборки. Как вариант попробуйте посмотреть кросс сборки через QEMU. PS Вы большинство мелких либ ставите через пакетный менджер?  Советую потратить время на это.

Comment: PS линку на либу дайте пожалуста.

Comment: @JK_Action
Исходники activemq-cpp: http://activemq.apache.org/cms/download.html

Исходники apr: https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi (так же добавил в тело вопроса)

Comment: оформите как ответ

Answer (score 4):

**Шаг 1.** Кросс-компиляция apr-1:

1. Скачал исходники из https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi

Дальше идет описание *грязного хака*, но без него не получилось

2. Разархивируем в папку `apr-1.5.2_local`, стандартно компилируем (под локальную машину):

   ./configure
   make

Внимание, не инсталим! Нам теперь понадобятся файлы из `apr-1.5.2_local/tools` в дальнейшем (в этом и заключается "грязный хак")

3. Разархивируем снова в папку `apr-1.5.2_arm`
4. Конфигурю с помощью следующих флагов (если кто найдет более оптимальный набор флагов, напишите коммент):

   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/arm/usr --with-sysroot=$HOME/olimex --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux CPPFLAGS=-I$HOME/arm/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/arm/usr/lib CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
               ac_cv_file__dev_zero="yes" \
               ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void="yes" \
               apr_cv_process_shared_works="yes" \
               apr_cv_mutex_robust_shared="no" \
               apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork="yes" \
               ac_cv_sizeof_struct_iovec="8" \
               apr_cv_mutex_recursive="yes"
5. Копируем файлы из `apr-1.5.2_local/tools` в `apr-1.5.2_arm/tools`

Пояснение: Дело в том, что в процессе make'а генерируется и **выполняется** бинарный файл `tools/gen_test_char`, а на 64-битной машине 32-битная бинарка не распознается и не выполняется. **Если кто знает, как обойти это скользкое место, прошу отписаться.**

6. Выполняю `make` со своим набором компиляторов (кажется, тут нужен только си, без плюсов, но не помешал):

   make CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
7. `sudo make install` (заинсталил в $HOME/arm/usr)

---

С помощью этого пока удалось кросскомпилировать `ActiveMQ` без поддержки `openssl` следующей конфигурацией:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/arm/usr --with-sysroot=$HOME/olimex --host=arm-linux --with-apr=$HOME/arm/usr CPPFLAGS=-I$HOME/arm/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/arm/usr/lib CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ CFLAGS=-pthread LDFLAGS=-lpthread LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/arm/usr/lib -disable-ssl
```

Comment: а источник почему не указан?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Источник чего?

Comment: вот этот [источник](http://hostciti.net/faq/c-plus/krosskompilyatsiya-activemqcpp.html)

Comment: @Senior Pomidor это кто-то отсюда туда скопипастил (а не наоборот) (это легко распознается по дате, мой вопрос задан 3 мар в 12:25, а тот 
29
07 марта 2017, 17:13)

Comment: дата публицации статьи 07 марта 2017, 17:13, а твой ответ задан 11 марта. ладно, не хочу спорить.

Comment: @Senior Pomidor и не надо спорить, мой задан задан 3 мар в 12:25, 11 марта он "последний раз изменен". Все ведь легко проверяется

Comment: Написал в support@hostciti.net с просьбой указать ссылку на первоисточник

Comment: @Senior Pomidor они добавили у себя источник на эту страницу.

Comment: искренее прошу прощения.

Comment: Senior Pomidor Принимается :)